# SP 2010 migration to SP 2013 does not show webpart

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I migrated SP 2010 site collection to my new SP 2013 using db backup process from [here](http://passionatetechie.blogspot.in/2012/07/migrating-site-from-sharepoint-2010-to.html). Site is working fine but the custom web parts I created in SP 2010 is not visible in SP 2013. Below error is shown in place of my web part.

[Web Part Error: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type DemoSharePointUserControl.LyncWebPart.LyncWebPart, DemoSharePointUserControl, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3656b399b713ff03 could not be found or it is not registered as safe. Correlation ID: 2d9c179c-2f58-5051-5762-87aea7d1d9ef]

How can I solve it?? 
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the "safecontrols" directive is now missing from web.config file. Either re-deploy the solution which contains the feature of this web part or add it manually (not suggested on live servers)

Answer (score 0):

There are  number of Commercial content migration tools that migrate from sharepoint 2010 to 2013. Some them are metalogix,Tzunami and other. I am using tzunami tool which migrate webpart and other content.